# How to config more than one CNAME to point to the Azure storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cname

I found the images storing in the Azure storage are slow to load in the browser. So I want to config more than one CNAME to point to the Azure storage. But I found I can config only one CNAME to point to the Azure storage.

Please let me know how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: I'm not sure how having multiple CNAME pointing to same storage account will solve the problem of slow loading. Have you identified the reason for slowness?

Comment: The limit in browsers like Chrome, Firefox and IE is 6 concurrent downloads from the same domain/sub-domain. So if I can point 5 CNAME records to one BLOB storage I can get maximum download parallelism for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Mark,
You can configure a custom domain name for blob data in an Azure storage account. You can create a customer domain name and then map your customer domain to your blob endpoint by following the following article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/

Please also note a single blob target throughput of 60 MBytes/sec. If you need a higher throughput, you will need to create multiple blobs or spread the blobs across multiple storage accounts depending on your throughput requirements.

Aung